# "Follow the below sets" should be "Follow the below steps"

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams

Cancel your subscription page:

https://www.stackoverflow.help/support/solutions/articles/36000052533-cancel-your-subscription-

Says the following:

> Follow the below **sets** to cancel your subscription

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This issue has now been resolved.

Comment: [Follow The Steps Below OR Follow The Below Steps?](https://www.englishforums.com/English/FollowStepsBelowFollowBelowSteps/mvvm/post.htm)

Comment: @user4412195 I agree with your implication that it should be "steps below"